# Сделать равную высоту заголовков и текста в независимости от количества текста в них

Tags: css, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать все заголовки равной высоты и блоки текста, т.е. чтобы все заголовки были равной высоты между собой, а блоки текста равны по высоте между собой?

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 .btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h3><span class="label label-primary">1</span> Заголовок 1</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis!</p>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h3><span class="label label-primary">2</span> Заголовок длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный 2</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h3><span class="label label-primary">3</span> Заголовок длинный 3</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis!</p>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать `h3` желаемую высоту и `overflow: hidden`:

```
h3 {
  height: 2.3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.row-eq-height .col-sm-4 .btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">1</span> Заголовок 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">2</span> Заголовок длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный-длинный 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3><span class="label label-primary">3</span> Заголовок длинный 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, quidem dignissimos placeat amet fugiat consectetur labore sunt sequi repellat officiis!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем коде фиксированная высота и обрезается заголовок, понятно же, что это нежелательный результат, как сделать чтобы заголовки не обрезались и были одинаковой высоты?

Comment: "понятно же..." - да ниоткуда это не понятно. Из вопроса этого не следует. На массе сайтов в ТЗ указывают обрезание слишком длинных текстовых элементов. У вас и так блоки все одной высоты. Если же вам надо, чтобы все заголовки были одной высоты, а потом текст одной высоты, а потом кнопки, то каждый набор элементов должен быть в своем ряду. Иначе никак. Изменил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Но если каждый набор элементов будет в своем ряду, то на маленьких экранах это будет выглядеть как набор несвязанных элементов, то есть сначала три заголовка, потом три блока текста и потом три кнопки...

Comment: Это да, но и этого в вопросе не было. Поэтому когда верстают карточки товаров, в которых много информации, идут на то, что просто режут длинные тексты. Это сплошь и рядом в woocommerce.